# including several jar projects into one WAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I have 4 maven projects that should work as one application, one parent project who is responsible for building all other, one war project with jsf and beans, one jpa project with entities and one ejb project with dao and ejb layer. I try to run on tomee server my .war, but it doesn't include the other classes from jpa and ajb project...Here are poms:

EclipseJPA2-parent:

```
....
<groupId>pka</groupId>
<artifactId>EclipseJPA2-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>EclipseJPA2</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../EclipseJPA2-war</module>
            <module>../EclipseJPA2-jpa</module>
            <module>../EclipseJPA2-ejb</module>
        </modules>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pka</groupId>
            <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-war</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pka</groupId>
            <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pka</groupId>
            <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.1 -->
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeVersion>1.5.2</tomeeVersion>
                    <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
                    <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

EclipseJPA2-jpa:

```
     ...
 <parent>
    <groupId>pka</groupId>
    <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>EclipseJPA2-jpa</artifactId>
<name>EclipseJPA2-jpa</name>
<description></description>

<dependencies>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

EclipseJPA2-ejb:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>pka</groupId>
    <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>EclipseJPA2-ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>EclipseJPA2-ejb</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pka</groupId>
        <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
     ...
</dependencies>
```

and EclipseJPA2-war

```
...
<artifactId>EclipseJPA2-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>EclipseJPA2-war</name>
<parent>
    <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>pka</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pka</groupId>
        <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-jpa</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pka</groupId>
        <artifactId>EclipseJPA2-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <version.primefaces>3.5</version.primefaces>
    <version.primefaces.themes>1.0.9</version.primefaces.themes>
</properties>
<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>
```

Do you know how to properly link those projects and include jars in war ?

mvn package output:

```
....                                                                        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EclipseJPA2-jpa 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa -      --
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e.  build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\usr\java\moje\system\EclipseJPA2-jpa\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
  T E S T S
 -------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ EclipseJPA2-jpa ---
....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EclipseJPA2-ejb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\usr\java\moje\system\EclipseJPA2-ejb\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) @ EclipseJPA2-ejb ---
[INFO] Building EJB EclipseJPA2-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT with EJB version 3.1
[INFO] Building jar: D:\usr\java\moje\system\EclipseJPA2-ejb\target\EclipseJPA2-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Building EJB client EclipseJPA2-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-client
[INFO] Building jar: D:\usr\java\moje\system\EclipseJPA2-ejb\target\EclipseJPA2-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-client.jar
....
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong per se. Are the other dependencies added to the war. What is the output of mvn package?

Comment: you may want to use the maven-ear-plugin instead

Comment: Andreas, I edited my post and added mvn package output, I hope it helps... guido, will maven-ear-plugin generate .war with jars from other projects?